# C - Return a modified array of integers using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

i'm tryng to modify an array of integers in C, and in the end I want to return a pointer to the array, but it seems it doesn't work

```
int *h(int *a) {
 int b[10];
 while(*a) {
  *b = *a;
  b++;
  a++;
 }
 return b;
}
```

I don't know what to do , I'm new to C

Comment: You return a pointer to the first element of the *local* array `b`. When the function returns, the life-time of `b` ends. The pointer you return will become immediately invalid.

Comment: A common solution is to have the caller pass in a pointer to its own array, and you use that. Like `int *h(int *a, int *b) { ...; return b; }` Typically the size of both the source and destination arrays are also provided, to help prevent going out of bounds.

Comment: On a couple of different notes, you know that arrays are not naturally terminated by a "zero"? Only strings are null-terminated. Also, what happens if the called wants to use zero as one of the array elements? And please don't use non-descriptive single-letter names for your variable. Give them some meaning full name that makes the code easier to understand.

Comment: Oh I just discovered two other problem with the code you have: `b++`. That won't work with the code you currently have, because `b` is an *array*, not a pointer. You can't "increase" an array, that makes no sense. Also, if you fix the problem by passing the destination as an argument, you will loose the original pointer and can't return it. If you need to return a pointer, save a copy of the original pointer and return that copy (or use the copy in the loop).

Comment: How the code should looks like? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Well to be frank and IMO, the "correct" solution would be to not write this function to begin with, but to use the standard [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) function instead. But if it's a requirement to write the function (assignment or exercise requires it), then the answer (even though it looks like it's from ChatGPT, which is disallowed here) shows one posibility. But I would rename `a` as `source`, `b` as `destination, and the function itself as `copy`.

Comment: Instead of stating something pointless like "does not work", you should include the compiler errors you are getting in the question. It's kind of fundamental to the problem that the code won't even compile, which might not be obvious at a glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

First off, you've declared `b` as a local array inside your function. In C, local arrays live on the stack, which means they get cleaned up after your function is done. When you return a pointer to `b`, you're actually pointing to a spot that's not yours anymore once the function exits.

Second, there's this thing where you're trying to increment `b`, the array itself. In C, the name of the array is kind of a constant pointer to the first element. You can't move it around like a regular pointer.

Now, how do we fix this? There are a few ways:

1. Instead of creating `b` inside the function, why not create it outside and just pass it in? This way, you manage its life outside the function, and there's no risk of it disappearing after the function ends.
2. Second solution. Allocate `b` dynamically using `malloc`. This puts `b` on the heap, not the stack, so it sticks around after the function is over. Just remember, what you allocate, you must deallocate. So, you'll need to `free` this memory when you're done, or else you'll have a memory leak.

Possible solution to your problem:

```
void h(int *a, int *b, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int b[5]; 
    h(a, b, 5);

    //use b here
}
```